# Link similar elements in list python to create a dictionary

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python.

I have these 2 lists:

```
a=['a','b','c','c','d']
b=['1','2','3','4','5']
```

Now, I want to  create a dictionary where key is the index position and values are a list of the elements of same elements.

```
a=['a','b','c','c','d']
b=['1','2','3','4','5']

d={a[i]:b[i] for i in range(len(a))}
print(d)
```

Expected output:

```
{0: ['a', '1'], 1: ['b', '2'], 2: ['c', '3'], 3: ['c', '4'], 4: ['d', '5']}
```

Currently, this is the code I have above. I am not sure how to continue forward. Please help me!

Also, if something obvious is missing, please be gentle `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with `enumerate` by `zip`ping the common elements.

Basically, `zip()` returns a tuple containing the elements with similar indexes. So you can use `zip()` for that matter.

Next, `enumerate` returns a Counter, starting from 0. So combining those 2, you can get the answer.

```
a=['a','b','c','c','d']
b=['1','2','3','4','5']

d={i:list(j) for i,j in enumerate(zip(a,b))}
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind `tuple` instead of `list` in the values you can do it with 2 `zip()`, first onw between the lists to create the values and another one between the values and `rang()` for the keys

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
b = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
d = dict(zip(range(len(a)), zip(a, b)))
print(d) # {0: ('a', '1'), 1: ('b', '2'), 2: ('c', '3'), 3: ('c', '4'), 4: ('d', '5')}
```